# При одинаковом запросе но в разные таблицы Mysql добавляется строка только в одну таблицу

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, что не так?
Делаю вот такой запрос в MySQL из файла add.php

```
<?php

include ("db.php");

if(isset($_POST['add'])){

   $title = strip_tags(trim($_POST['title']));
   $text = strip_tags(trim($_POST['text']));
   $author = strip_tags(trim($_POST['author']));
   $date = $_POST['date'];
   $time = $_POST['time'];

   mysql_query(" 
      INSERT INTO russ (title, text, date, time, author)
      VALUES ('$title', '$text', '$date', '$time', '$author') 
   ");

   mysql_close();
   echo "Новость уcпешно добавлена!";

}

?>
```

Все работает! 
Но если меняю в файле add.php, в INSERT INTO russ на angl, то ничего в таблицу angl не добавляется, но и ошибок не выдает никаких.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может, таблица не существует?

Comment: проблема к использовании зарезервированных слов в качестве названия столбцов таблиц. Пора бы уже научиться самом смотреть на ошибки https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-error.php